# Vungle video ads not working with some devices

Tags: android, ads, vungle-ads

I have integrated Vungle test video ads in my android app. It working fine with one of my devices which is running on Android 6.0 but it is not working with my other two devices running on Android 5.0.

Is it because the ads are in test mode?

Answer (score 1):

I am Gabor from Vungle, I am an Integration Engineer.

Our ads work fine on Android 4.0+, and you should have no issue running it on Android 5.

If you could share Vungle APP ID I could have a look on your app setup and the traffic you generated to see why you did not see any ads.

Gabor

Comment: Is there any official Mail Id through which i can contact you / give you my App ID. I have already contacted Vungle tech support but i was told to reintegrate the ads.

Comment: You can contact us by mail tech-support@vungle.com. If you already had this and had a ticket please refer to it and if you want feel free to mention me and I will have a look for you.

Comment: Thanks. Will try reintegrating the ads and then get back to you.